# Pulling some values from Mongo DB but not all using nodejs with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Below is my code, its does pull some fields from DB but not all, I am stuck on this for almost 2 days now, kindly help me fix this bug.

I need to pull data from mongo DB and I am failing to pull all the fields

```
router.get('/areas', (req, res) => {
  area
    .find()
    .exec()
    .then((foundarea) => {
      console.log(foundarea[0].name);
      res.render('areas/areas.ejs', { areas: foundarea });
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(foundarea);
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: needs a little more clarification. Where is `area` intialized and what is it supposed to be? What library do you use to connect to the DB, what kind of DB is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
area.find().select({"name":1, "column2":1})
     .exec()
```

just put name of the column and :1 to include it in the result.